# Clean diagnose of a lagging DVD drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, drivers, dvd

I bought 3 old DVD drives that were used in servers 20 years ago.

When plugging one of them into a PCI card on my Windows PC :

- It powers up
- The BIOS of my PCI card says "Not a Disk Drive" which seems abnormal
- When Windows boots successfully, I see the drive in Device Manager

However I face several issues :

- the DVD drive makes a repetitive noise, like it is trying to read something
- On boot, I often face Black screen of death (with white mouse)
- I am able to boot on Safe Mode, but Windows lags. It stops lagging when the drive stops its repetitive noise (see above).

These problems happen with all 3 drives, so they are not hardware-faulty.

I think this is a firmware problem : how do I confirm this ? How could I see logs of errors happening between Windows and my drive to further diagnose ?

Comment: Given this item is $8 https://www.newegg.com/toshiba-samsung-model-ts-t632-dvd-burner/p/1B1-002K-00003?Description=dvd%20drive&cm_re=dvd_drive-_-9SIA6BM3ZZ7004-_-Product  why struggle so hard with 20 year old junk.

Comment: +1 for 'junk'...